# Converting Mutidimensional array into json format

Tags: arrays, json, dictionary

I have result array from database like this

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [days] => October, 2014 [ispaid] => 1 [total] => 1683 [sales] => 3 ) [1] => Array ( [days] => September, 2014 [ispaid] => 1 [total] => 521 [sales] => 5 ) )
```

Now i want to convert it in json format like

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Month', 'Sales', 'Leads', 'Earnings'],
      **['January 2014', 171, 171, 520],
      ['February 2014', 192, 125, 2258],
      ['March 2014', 62, 142, 1725],
      ['April 2014', 115, 150, 1412],
      ['May 2014', 48, 265, 1586],
      ['June 2014', 556, 185, 1589]**
    ]);
```

How could I do that

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the `json_encode` function? It should convert any PHP array to a JSON string